# Non existent menu item showing up in Google search

Tags: php, html, xml, wordpress, api

[image]I have a menu item which is showing up in Google search, despite no such menu item existing. I haven't created the menu item on my site, or included it in the menu. So where does it come from?

The link is:
https://4309.co.uk/xmlrpc.php?rsd

```
<rsd  
xmlns="http://archipelago
.phrasewise.com/rsd" 
version="1.0">
<service> 
<engineName>WordPress
</engineName>  
<engineLink>https:/
/wordpress.org/</
engineLink> 
<homePageLink>https:
//4309.co.uk</homePageLink>
<apis>
<api name="WordPress" 
blogID="1" preferred="true"  
apiLink="https://4309.
co.uk/xmlrpc.php"/>
<api name="Movable Type" 
blogID="1" 
preferred="false"  
apiLink="https://4
309.co.uk/xmlrpc.php"/>
<api name="MetaWeblog" 
blogID="1" 
preferred="false"  
apiLink="https://4309.c
o.uk/xmlrpc.php"/>
<api name="Blogger" 
blogID="1" preferred
="false" 
apiLink="https://4309
.co.uk/xmlrpc.php"/>
<api name="WP-API" 
blogID="1" preferred
="false"  apiLink="https://
4309.co.uk/wp-json/"/>
</apis>
</service>
</rsd>
```

When i Google the link http above, in the document, i get http://archipelago.phrasewise.com/rsd/

Comment: What menu item, specifically?

Comment: If you Google 4309.co.uk on Google mobile, it comes up with site menu items. One of which is  https://4309.co.uk/xmlrpc.php?rsd. That shouldn't be there. Why is it?

Comment: 4309.co.uk on mobile from the search bar

Comment: Just checked on my phone and I don't see that link. The ones that display for me are _Drawing_, _Sketches_, _ABOUT_, _DRAWING DEVELOPMENT_, _Contact_, _Greetings Cards_, and _SERVICES_.

Comment: Please see photo. At the bottom `WordPress https`

Comment: Oddly enough, as I mentioned before, I don't see that.

Comment: Ah.... What to do?

Comment: Does WordPress have a menu.php and could i locate and delete it there? If so, how would I find it amd what would i be looking for?